# PHP message based on a certain time on different days

Tags: php, timezone, message

I'm trying to make an messages appear on my website when we are open and when the phones are "closed" but I can't seem to get it working.

This is what I have so far (This is my inspiration http://codewalkers.com/c/a/Date-Time-Code/Display-message-according-to-hour-of-day/)

```
<?php
//Change message of the day
$open = 'We are open for business';
$closed = 'We are closed';

//Get the current time
$current_time = date(G);
//Get the current day
$current_day = date(I);

if ($current_day == "Monday" && $current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 21) {
    echo $open;
}

elseif ($current_day == "Monday" && $current_time >= 21 && $current_time <= 9) {
    echo $closed; 
}

if ($current_day == "Tuesday" && $current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 21) {
    echo $open;
}

elseif ($current_day == "Tuesday" && $current_time >= 21 && $current_time <= 9) {
    echo $closed; 
}

if ($current_day == "Wednesday" && $current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 21) {
    echo $open;
}

elseif ($current_day == "Wednesday" && $current_time >= 21 && $current_time <= 9) {
    echo $closed; 
}

if ($current_day == "Thursday" && $current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 21) {
    echo $open;
}

elseif ($current_day == "Thursday" && $current_time >= 21 && $current_time <= 9) {
    echo $closed; 
}

if ($current_day == "Friday" && $current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 19) {
    echo $open;
}

elseif ($current_day == "Friday" && $current_time >= 19 && $current_time <= 9) {
    echo $closed; 
}

if ($current_day == "Saturday") {
    echo $closed;
}

if ($current_day == "Sunday") {
    echo $closed;
}
```

?>

and im getting this error message

```
Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in - on line 7 Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in - on line 9
```

It would be nice to have some qualified help :)

Comment: You did not say what kind of error, or error message, if any, you are getting. And by the way did you mean `date('G');` and `date('I');` ?

Comment: I've updatede my question and I hope that it is now sufficient.

Comment: Do not forget day light savings either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The qualified help you requested comes in the form of the script below:

Also note that in your code you have to use date('l') - lowercase L.

The list of timezones you can use for date_default_timezone_set() can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam'); // set it to the right value

$weAreOpen = areWeOpen(date('l'), date('G'));

if($weAreOpen) {
    echo 'We are open for business';
} else {
    echo 'We are closed';
}

/**
 * Test if we're open for business
 * @param string $day - day of week (ex: Monday)
 * @param string $hour - hour of day (ex: 9)
 * @return bool - true if open interval 
 */
function areWeOpen($day, $hour) {
    $hour = (int)$hour;
    switch($day) {
        case 'Monday':
        case 'Tuesday':
        case 'Wednesday':
        case 'Thursday':
            if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case 'Friday':
            if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 19) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The obvious thing that this answer has special is, it is VERY DIFFERENT from the original code. I'm not sure that "qualified help" means "code rewrite or revision". @Daniel, I have to say that it seems impolite to have silently ignored the 3 answers prior to this one, though they endeavoured to keep to your code structure, CHANGING ONLY WHAT WAS WRONG WITH YOUR CODE. That's would better conform to the spirit of StackOverflow. Sorry if I am ranting ;-)

Comment: I did not ignored the other answers I'm sorry that you feel that way it was not what I intended

Comment: In my opinion, this code is very easy to understand and maintain over time. :-)

Comment: Im still new at this and this code works better (more logical) structure (for me)

Answer (score 0):

So perhaps this will solve your problem:

```
//Get the current time
$current_time = date('G');
//Get the current day
$current_day = date('l');//This is lowercase 'L' and NOT 'I' as in "India".
```

And as far as I know, php `date()` accepts string as first argument. And the G and L can only work well if you had earlier defined them as `constants`...

**EDIT**

Seeing your updated question with the error message, you can try this:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Africa/Lagos');' //somewhere at the top of your code.
```

Or else you could place this in you php configuration file (e.g. `php.ini` in windows):

```
date.timezone = Africa/Lagos
```

Then, of course, replace "Africa/Lagos" with the timezone of your choice. And for a list of supported timezones, [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Answer (score 0):

`date()` takes a string, and your code could be shorter:

```
//Change message of the day
$open = 'We are open for business';
$closed = 'We are closed';

$current_time = date('G'); //Get the current time
$current_day = date('w'); //Get the current day

if ($current_day > 0 && $current_day < 6) //Monday to Friday
{
  if ($current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 21 && $current_day != 5) //Monday to Thursday between 9 and 21
    echo $open;
  else if ($current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 19 && $current_day == 5) //Friday between 9 and 19
    echo $open;
  else
    echo $closed;
}
else //Saturday and Sunday
  echo $closed;
```

About your warning, open your `php.ini` and add this block if you don't have it:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Asia/Seoul
```

You can also just add this line at the beginning of your code: `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Seoul');`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php for the list of supported timezones.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    //Change message of the day
    $open = 'We are open for business';
    $closed = 'We are closed';

    //Get the current time
    $current_time = date("G");
    //Get the current day
    $current_day = date("l");

    if ($current_day == "Monday" && $current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 21) {
        echo $open;
    }

    elseif ($current_day == "Monday" && $current_time >= 21 && $current_time <= 9) {
        echo $closed; 
    }

    if ($current_day == "Tuesday" && $current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 21) {
        echo $open;
    }

    elseif ($current_day == "Tuesday" && $current_time >= 21 && $current_time <= 9) {
        echo $closed; 
    }

    if ($current_day == "Wednesday" && $current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 21) {
        echo $open;
    }

    elseif ($current_day == "Wednesday" && $current_time >= 21 && $current_time <= 9) {
        echo $closed; 
    }

    if ($current_day == "Thursday" && $current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 21) {
        echo $open;
    }

    elseif ($current_day == "Thursday" && $current_time >= 21 && $current_time <= 9) {
        echo $closed; 
    }

    if ($current_day == "Friday" && $current_time >= 9 && $current_time <= 19) {
        echo $open;
    }

    elseif ($current_day == "Friday" && $current_time >= 19 && $current_time <= 9) {
        echo $closed; 
    }

    if ($current_day == "Saturday") {
        echo $closed;
    }

    if ($current_day == "Sunday") {
        echo $closed;
    }

    ?>
```